# async and fast path optimization

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, async-await, .net-4.5

i was doing some refactoring on an OWIN project and i came across some issue about
c# fast path optimization.

So i read about best practises regarding pre-computed Tasks, make a method async or not and stuff like that.

More precisely, on the fast path optimization:

Task-based Asynchronous Pattern best practices (fast path p9) http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957

same guidance as for iterator, wich was as first more understandable for me as i'm quite new to TAP
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d9146792-1b9a-4807-a42e-29107c281cc4/can-awaiting-taskfromresult-introduce-concurrency?forum=async

So here is the code i came across:

```
public class CustomMiddleware2 : OwinMiddleware
{
    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        await InvokeInternal(context);
    }

    private Task InvokeInternal(IOwinContext context)
    {           
        if (Wacko.WhatDOuKnow)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/awesomeurl");

            //fast path
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
        return Next.Invoke(context);
    }

    public CustomMiddleware2(OwinMiddleware next)
        : base(next)
    {

    }

}
```

and here is the replacement i actually plan to do:

```
public class BetterOrNotMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        if (Wacko.WhatDOuKnow)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/awesomeurl");

            //fast path
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);

        }
        else
            return InvokeInternal(context);
    }

    private async Task InvokeInternal(IOwinContext context)
    {
        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }

    public BetterOrNotMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next)
        : base(next)
    {

    }

}
```

The thing is, there is not so much differences. I'm not sure the BetterOrNotMiddleware class is more optimized or proper?
it feel more adequate to me to await on the Next.Invoke call, and the code may feel more understandable because
it's the same pattern for exception handling with iterators(link above)

i may be missing something about async state machine or call stack wich would validate the second approach, but i'm too new to async to get it.

but if all this is just a micro optimization i'm not sure i want to bother to change all the middlewares in the application. Well, i may nonetheless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are *almost* **exactly** the same. There's no real difference between the two options, other than not having to make a second method call (which could be optimized by the compiler anyway).

You can simply have just one method that does everything:

```
public class BetterOrNotMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    private static readonly Task CompletedTask = Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        if (Wacko.WhatDOuKnow)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/awesomeurl");
            // fast path
            return CompletedTask;
        }
        else
        {
            return Next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

**Edit:** There's actually no reason to create a new task each time, so I use a static completed task instead.

Comment: in all the middleware owin sample i remember, there is an await for the next.invoke call.
one cannot know what the next middleware is up to, so i suppose people play it safe with await.
this explain the second async method.
Do you think this is useless, and not awaiting the next.invoke call can never be a bad thing?

Comment: @Bombinosh Invoke itself returns a task which should be awaited by the caller. When you simply return the `Next.Invoke(context)` task then it will await it. If the root caller doesn't await, it wouldn't matter if you would await `Next.Invoke(context);`

Comment: @Bombinosh a problem that may occur when you don't await a task is when there's an exception. But if you await the internal task and the caller doesn't await the outside task the exception would still be unhandled

Answer (score 2):

In the first code sample, why bother awaiting at all?

```
public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
    return InvokeInternal(context);
}
```

Same can be said of the second code sample, you can make both samples entirely fast-path so they are near enough identical.

The `InvokeInternal` method seems pointless to me, just put the logic straight in `Invoke`, i.e.

```
public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
    if (Wacko.WhatDOuKnow)
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/awesomeurl");

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);

    }
    return Next.Invoke(context);
}
```